Temporal dead zone
So, I was reading about this so-called "temporal dead zone," where accessing a variable before declaring will cause a reference error (unless it's a var). So I've been wondering, so since it explicitly said that "before" declaring the variable, does it mean that when trying to execute the program (I assume in the parsing stage where it makes the AST), it will first acknowledge all identifiers (variable names) before putting their values? So imagine that there's a step-by-step process for making the tree, and it will first add the identifier names, then maybe, after a few steps, add all the values for it.
Clear explanation I guess

Variables declared with var and function declarations are "hoisted" to the top of their enclosing scope. It's important to understand we're talking just about the declaration and not the initialization/assignment. This is why you can refer to a var variable or function before it appears in the code sequence. This doesn't happen with let variables, so you can only access them after the spot where they are declared has been processed.

This generally has little to do with how you create the AST. This is done by the compiler in additional passes over the AST. Except in languages like C, where the type of a syntax node depends on previous declarations (e.g. variable name vs. typedef name), parsing usually doesn't need this kind of cross-referencing.

"it will first acknowledge all identifiers before putting their values?" - yes, and that does happen in the parsing stage before the evaluation of the code, not during the execution. In the execution stage, it then already knows which identifiers are to be declared, it doesn't have to search through the AST every time.
